# Improvements in the customized question environment

Tags: exam

I am following a customized question environment that ends with an empty square at the end of the question on the right side of the page.

If questions end with some text instead of the math environment, it works well. However, if the question ends in the mathematical environment, an extra space appears between the last line of the math environment and the ending square.

The minimal working example is

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,color, xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\newcounter{ques}[chapter]

\newenvironment{question}[2][Question \stepcounter{ques}\arabic{ques}:]{\begin{trivlist}
        \item[\hskip \labelsep \bfseries #1] #2 \par \textbf{Answer:}} {\hfill{$\square$} \end{trivlist} }
    
\begin{document}
\begin{question}{Find $\Sigma X$, if $\overline{X}=15$, $n=10$}
    \begin{align*}
        \overline{X} &=\frac{\Sigma X}{n}\\
        15 & = \frac{\Sigma X}{10} \\
        \Rightarrow \Sigma X & = 15\times 10=150
    \end{align*}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{The mean of 10 numbers is 8. If an eleventh number is added, the mean becomes 9. What is the eleventh value?}
    \begin{align*}
        \text{Mean of 10 numbers } &= 8\\
        \text{Mean of 11 numbers } &= 9\\
        \text{Total of 10 numbers} &= 80\\
        \text{Total of 11 numbers} &= 99\\
        \therefore \text{value of eleventh number} &= 99-88 = 19
    \end{align*}
So, the value of eleventh number is = 199
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Valuable input is required for the improvement of the customized question environment

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LuaTeX, it is easy to implement some pattern matching and string manipulation functions on the Lua side to achieve this.

To make the code short, I am writing the manipulated string to the file system and have LaTeX read from it. This can be potentially slow if the number of question environment is large. If it is necessary, there is a way to let LuaTeX `\input` from memory. For more information, see [here](https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2020/07/07/luatex-mimic-input.html).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,color, xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{luacode*}
local spacer = lpeg.S(" \t\f\v")
local nonspacer = 1 - spacer
local stripper = spacer^0 * lpeg.C((spacer^0 * nonspacer^1)^0)

function strip(str)
    return str and lpeg.match(stripper, str) or ""
end

verb_table = {}

function store_lines(str)
  if string.find (str , "\\end{question}" ) then
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
      "process_input_buffer" , "store_lines")
      return "\\end{question}"
  else
    table.insert(verb_table, str)
  end
  return ""
end

function register_verbatim()
  verb_table = {}
  luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "process_input_buffer" , store_lines , "store_lines")
end

local math_end = {
  ["\\end{align*}"] = 1,
  ["\\end{gather*}"] = 1,
  ["\\end{equation*}"] = 1,
  ["\\end{multline*}"] = 1,
}

function process_verbatim()
  local non_empty_lines = {}
  for ind, str in ipairs(verb_table) do
    str = strip(str)
    if str:len() > 0 then
      table.insert(non_empty_lines, ind)
    end
  end
  local last_line_ind = non_empty_lines[#non_empty_lines]
  local last_line = verb_table[last_line_ind]
  if math_end[strip(last_line)] ~= nil then
    -- make sure second to last line exists
    local last_two_line_ind = non_empty_lines[#non_empty_lines - 1]
    local last_two_line = verb_table[last_two_line_ind]
    assert(last_two_line ~= nil, "invalid math environment")
    last_two_line = last_two_line .. "\\tag*{$\\square$}"
    verb_table[last_two_line_ind] = last_two_line
  else
    last_line = last_line .. "\\hfill{$\\square$}"
    verb_table[last_line_ind] = last_line
  end
  local out_str = table.concat(verb_table, "\n")
  local file = io.open(tex.jobname .. ".tmp", "w")
  file:write(out_str)
  file:close()
end

\end{luacode*}

\newcounter{ques}[chapter]
\NewDocumentEnvironment{question}{O{Question \stepcounter{ques}\arabic{ques}:}m}{
\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep \bfseries #1] #2 \par \textbf{Answer:}
\directlua{register_verbatim()}
}{
\directlua{process_verbatim()}
\input{\jobname.tmp}
\end{trivlist}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{question}{Find $\Sigma X$, if $\overline{X}=15$, $n=10$}
    \begin{align*}
        \overline{X} &=\frac{\Sigma X}{n}\\
        15 & = \frac{\Sigma X}{10} \\
        \Rightarrow \Sigma X & = 15\times 10=150
    \end{align*}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{The mean of 10 numbers is 8. If an eleventh number is added, the mean becomes 9. What is the eleventh value?}
    \begin{align*}
        \text{Mean of 10 numbers } &= 8\\
        \text{Mean of 11 numbers } &= 9\\
        \text{Total of 10 numbers} &= 80\\
        \text{Total of 11 numbers} &= 99\\
        \therefore \text{value of eleventh number} &= 99-88 = 19
    \end{align*}
So, the value of eleventh number is = 199
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Alan Xiang: Can you help regarding LaTeX?

Comment: @itfeature.com LuaTeX is just LaTeX. Unless by `latex` you literally mean the old-fashioned executable which generates `dvi` files, `lualatex` is just like `pdflatex` and `xelatex`, which are members of modern LaTeX compilers. If you are not using `pdflatex`/`xelatex` specific features, your documents should be able to compile with LuaTeX.